Как реализовать поиск точки с минимальной плотностью в ограниченном плоском пространстве?
Как алгоритмически правильно решить задачу на поиск точки с минимальной плотностью (поиск самой разреженной точки)?
Искомая точка не содержится в наборе — её координаты нужно вычислить, "обнаружить".
Например для пространства [(0; 0); (1; 1)] содержащего нижеприведённые точки A₁, B₁, C₁ и D₁, искомой новой точкой является E₁ (0,5; 0,5):

То есть под искомой точкой E я подразумеваю такую точку в заданном пространстве, которая находилось бы на максимальном возможном расстоянии от всех остальных точек в нём. Иначе говоря такую, чтобы расстояние от неё до другой ближайшей точки в пространстве было максимальным.

А каково определение точки с минимальной плотностью?

@Harry Под искомой точкой E я подразумеваю такую точку, которая находилось бы на максимальном возможном расстоянии от всех остальных точек. Иначе говоря такую, чтобы расстояние от неё до другой ближайшей точки было максимальным.

Но такая точка находится в бесконечности :) Но если даже искать в заданной области, что что означает максимальное расстояние? Максимум среди расстояний до точек? Максимум суммы расстояний? Произведения? Среднеквадратичного расстояния? :) Что именно понимается под максимальным возможным расстоянием от всех остальных точек?

@Harry Ну я же уточнил что речь об ограниченном пространстве. Например на рисунке это квадрат [(0; 0); (1; 1)]. Но если у вас есть на уме какое-то решение для круга, то мне и оно сойдёт.

Я же написал вопрос: Что именно понимается под максимальным возможным расстоянием от всех остальных точек? Это поиск точки, для которой максимальна сумма расстояний до всех точек? Максимально максимальное расстояние? Максимально минимальное расстояние? О чем идет речь?

@Harry Речь о точке в заданном пространстве, которая находилось бы на максимальном возможном расстоянии от всех остальных точек в нём.

С виду тут наоборот какой-то центр тяжести. То есть наименьшее суммарное расстояние до остальных точек. Потому что по ближайшему расстоянию все точки эквивалентны. Они на одинаковом расстоянии от одной ближайшей точки.

Автору - я интерпретировал так: Найти точку набора, для которой окружность с центром в данной точке, не содержащая других точек, имеет наибольший радиус. Это верно?

@MBo, да. Эта задача может быть сформулирована как поиск максимальной пустой окружности. Максимальной в смысле радиуса. Пустой - без пересечения её внутренности с множеством.

@MBo Не совсем: искомая точка не содержится в наборе — её координаты нужно вычислить, "обнаружить".

Ясно. Тогда второй способ не к месту, а диаграмма Вороного всё равно поможет.

За N^4 можно решить элементарными средствами. За NlogN - с помощью диаграммы Вороного.

ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78711401

Строим диаграмму Вороного за O(n log n).
Кроме того, строим выпуклую оболочку точек.
Теперь возможные центры наибольшей пустой окружности - это узлы диаграммы, лежащие внутри оболочки, а также пересечения ребер диаграммы с выпуклой оболочкой. Из этих центров выбирается тот, что обеспечивает наибольший радиус (это может оказаться не так просто, но для небольшого количества точек проще проверить все расстояния от центров-кандидатов)
Статья по теме

Теперь я уже точно не понимаю, что такое "максимально возможное расстояние от всех остальных точек" :)

@Harry Да, формулировочка страдает ;) Однако, как мне кажется, ячейка диаграммы с наибольшей окружностью от точки - то, что автору требуется.

Кроме вершин диаграммы Вороного требуется рассматривать пересечение ребер диаграммы с границей прямоугольника. Тогда множество кандидатов в центры максимальных пустых окружностей будет просмотрено целиком.

В вершине диаграммы Вороного записаны индексы точек которые её определяют. В ребере - тоже. Когда диаграмма построена все вершины проверяются за линейное время. Также за линеное время проверяются пересечения ребер с границей прямоугольника.

Дан центр q. Окружность Cq называется пустой если никакие точки множества S не лежат внутри окружности. Максимальная пустая окружность - тоже самое с максимальным радиусом. Очевидно что радиус максимальной пустой окружности - непрерывная функция от q. Она ограничена, если точке q запрещено покидать некоторую компактную область (прямоугольник). Тогда она достигает своего максимума на этом компакте.
В дальнейшем Cq обозначает только максимальную пустую окружность.
Пересечение Cq c S не пусто - следствие максимальности.
Если в пересечении ровно одна точка p и q внутри области, то можно "отодвинуть" q от p и получить q', такую что радиус Cq' будет больше радиуса Cq.
Если в пересечении ровно две точки p1 и p2 и q внутри области, то можно "отодвинуть" q вдоль срединного перепендикуляра к отрезку p1p2 и получить q', такую что радиус Cq' будет больше радиуса Cq.
Если в пересечении ровно одна точка p и q внутри ребра области (то есть на границе но не в углу), её можно сдвинуть вдоль границы и получить больший радиус.
Отброшены три случая. Остались

точка q внутри области, на границе Cq три или больше точек S;

точка q внутри ребра области, на границе Cq две или больше точек S;

точка q в углу области.


Первая категория - вершины диаграммы Вороного. Вторая категория - пересечения рёбер диаграммы Вороного с границей области. Третья категория - вершины границы области. Все категории перебираются за линейное время, если вы умеете строить диаграмму Вороного.
Без построения диаграммы есть алгоритм за N4. Перебираете все тройки точек, по тройке строите окружность, проверяете её пустоту (время N4). Перебираете все пары точек, строите срединные перепендикуляры, пересекаете их с границей области, в пересечениях строите окружности, проверяете их пустоту (время KN2, K - число углов области). Во всех углах области строите максимальные пустые окружности (время NK, K - число углов области).
